# HasONE YII2 link with 2 attributes

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

````
``` public function getContaCorrente()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\app\models\ContaCorrente::className(), ['id' => 'conta_corrente_id']);
}```
````

**Is it possible to add two attributes in the same get? For example, I have this get above and I want to join it with the get below, as they both look for the same table but different variables.**

```
public function getContaCorrenteAdesao()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\app\models\ContaCorrente::className(), ['id' => 'conta_corrente_adesao']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a query builder you can do something like that:

```
public function getContaCorrenteAdesao()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\app\models\ContaCorrente::className(), ['id' => 'conta_corrente_adesao'])->orWhere(['id' => 'conta_corrente_id']);
}
```